# Wrapping up a vector to pointer parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a `Model` type that has double "parameters" and a vector of pointers to them, vector that I use for shifting up and back down the parameters to see how some member function depends on the params. The production setup is the following (description in comments) :

```
template <class T>
class Model
{
    T x_; //model parameter 1
    T y_; //model parameter 2
    std::vector<T*> parameters_; // vector of pointers to model parameters
    void setvpt() // setting the parameters pointers vector
    {
        parameters_[0] = &x_;
        parameters_[1] = &y_;
    }
public:
    template <class U>
    Model(const U x, const U y) : x_(x), y_(y), parameters_(2)
    {
        setvpt();
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Model<T>> clone() const
    {
        auto clone = std::make_unique<Model<T>>(*this);
        clone->setvpt(); // set the pointers
        return clone;
    }
    T expensive_method() const // an method numerically (CPU + RAM) expensive
    {
        return 0.5 * (x_ * x_ + y_ * y_);
    }
    const std::vector<T*>& params() { return parameters_; } // return by reference so I can change the parameters
};

template <class T> // wrapping up the expensive method
inline T expensive_function(const Model<T>& model)
{
    auto clone = model.clone();
    return clone->expensive_method();
}

template <class T> // the function where the changes of model params occur
inline auto expensive_function_sensitivities(const Model<T>& model)
{
    auto clone = model.clone();
    auto baseRes = expensive_function(*clone);
    std::vector<T> res(3);
    res[0] = baseRes;
    const auto params = clone->params();
    for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); ++i)
    {
        *params[i] += 1e-8; // changing the parameter by bumping it up by 1e-8
        auto bumpRes = expensive_function(*clone);
        *params[i] -= 1e-8; // switching the param back to its initial value
        res[i + 1] = 1e8 * (bumpRes - baseRes);
    }
    return res;
}

int main() // prod use case, print 1, 1 and 1
{
    std::unique_ptr<Model<double>> model_ptr = std::make_unique<Model<double>>(1.0, 1.0);
    const auto res = expensive_function_sensitivities(*model_ptr);
    for (const auto resval : res)
        std::cout << resval << std::endl;
}
```

(It is templated because in production my code is templated to be able to use other numerical types than double.)

Now, I want to be able to have parameters of an other nature that `T` : for instance, I would like to add to the two `T` parameters `x_, y_` an `std:::vector<T>` parameter, or a member function, which will have their own custom ways of being bumped up and down. The only step that I found it is by introducing the following `Parameter` class

```
template <class T>
class Parameter
{
    T& pvalue_;
public:
    template <class U>
    Parameter(U& value) : pvalue_(value) {}
    void tilt_up()
    {
        pvalue_ += 1e-8;
    }
    void tilt_down()
    {
        pvalue_ -= 1e-8;
    }
};
```

and the following model "interface" :

```
template <class T>
class ModelWithParameters
{
protected:
    std::vector<Parameter<T>*> parameters_;
public:
    ModelWithParameters(size_t nbParams) : parameters_(nbParams) {}
    std::vector<Parameter<T>*>& params() { return parameters_; }
    void set(T& value, size_t i)
    {
        parameters_[i] = new Parameter<T>(value);
    }
};
```

I make `Model` derive from `ModelWithParameters`, with the following changes :

```
template <class T>
class Model : public ModelWithParameters<T>
{
    T x_;
    T y_;
    void setvpt()
    {
        ModelWithParameters<T>::parameters_[0] = new Parameter<T>(x_);
        ModelWithParameters<T>::parameters_[1] = new Parameter<T>(y_);
    }
public:
    template <class U>
    Model(const U x, const U y) : ModelWithParameters<T>(2), x_(x), y_(y)
    {
        setvpt();
    }
    std::unique_ptr<Model<T>> clone() const
    {
        auto clone = std::make_unique<Model<T>>(*this);
        clone->setvpt();
        return clone;
    }
    T expensive_method() const
    {
        return 0.5 * (x_ * x_ + y_ * y_);
    }
};
```

And finally the change in `expensive_function_sensitivities` are :

```
template <class T>
inline auto expensive_function_sensitivities(const Model<T>& model)
{
    auto clone = model.clone();
    auto baseRes = expensive_function(*clone);
    std::vector<T> res(3);
    res[0] = baseRes;
    const auto params = clone->params();
    for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); ++i)
    {
        params[i]->tilt_up();
        auto bumpRes = expensive_function(*clone);
        params[i]->tilt_down();
        res[i + 1] = 1e8 * (bumpRes - baseRes);
    }
    return res;
}
```

This works and is simple. And (as far as I understand) it is the fact that `pvalue_` is a reference (and the fact that we have a reference on a vector of parameter pointers) that allows it to be bumped.

Now, this handles "constant" parameters, but I could need parameters that are a whole vector, or a lambda function, or even a member function, etc etc. Hence polymorphism, ok. But my problem is that I cannot get hold of what to do would I for instance want to generalize to the case where `pvalue_` would be an std vector.

Comment: For your issue, you could use a `std::reference_wrapper` instead of raw pointers. And you could then access your members through the vector without writing pointer indirection (consequently, you could remove your `Parameter` class).

Comment: I don't see the point in using pointers (`uniqe_ptr` + raw pointers) here. Are you trying to convert code from JAVA or other languages?

Comment: @Fareanor I'm quite new to C++ but I thought that in general (by the standard ?) the default (non implemented) copy ctor was doing shallow copy i.e. for non pointer types (which is the case for my `T`'s which will be either `double` or a custom type having a correct copy ctor) and hence that in my case it would be ok.

Comment: Moreover, if you want to copy an object, the copy constructor and copy assignment operator are for that purpose. Forget about those weird clone functions. The only use-case where a clone function is needed is when polymorphism is involved. Consequently, you don't need to use pointers everywhere, it's a very bad habit to use them by default.

Comment: @Fareanor how does `std::reference_wrapper` behave in terms of performance ?

Comment: @Fareanor I do in fact have polymorphism, `Model` is in fact an base class from which derive concrete model classes, hence the clone remaining an the design around it

Comment: @Red.Wave Nope, never coded in Java. Did in C# but no, here I have clone and unique ptr because in fact `Model` is polymorphic, I am just guilty of not having simplified my example enough

Comment: @11house `std::reference_wrapper` only does the pointer indirection for you, nothing more. [Here I wrote an example](https://godbolt.org/z/cjqdvza3Y) for your `Model` class.

Comment: @Fareanor But in any case, I will have to make `Parameters` polymorphic

Comment: @11house To be honest, your design seems wrong from the start, but anyway, if you want your parameter to be polymorphic, how about having `Model` templated for `T*` instead of `T` ? Or `Base *` (not templated anymore), or `Base<T>*`. I don't really see your real use-case so I can't tell which is better for you.

Comment: You should really reduce your code to be minimal (for example remove all the unnecessary functions) to make it more readable and easier to understand what you want. Maybe I missed your point but I find your question quite unclear :o For example, if I want polymorphic members in a class, I don't need all that boilerplate. But I'm not sure to have understood what you really want.

Comment: @Fareanor why wrong from the start ? parameter has to be polymorphic as in some cases I will have two T's, while in another case I'll jave three std::vector<T>'s

Comment: This is not what polymorphic means. But when I read that, this becomes more and more evident that the whole design seems flawed (undefined number of class members being vectors whom content points to other members, mixing template (compile-time) and polymorphism (runtime) over the same members, etc... all of this are huge design smells). I don't know the original problem you have to solve but I would advise you to step back and start again from the real problem. Of course you're free to ignore my advice !

Comment: @11house C# has a lot in common with JAVA. Reference semantics is generally not the primary option in C++ code. Design that uses value semantics is simpler and follows the intuitive **rule 0**. Once reference semantics is utilized, **rule 3** or **rule 5** become necessary. Current snippet is too complex to illustrate your intented use. You are gonna need crack down the design into different steps, and discuss the problematic part. If you need to store raw pointers, the design is most probably flawed.

Comment: I don't know if it would be of any help but [here I wrote](https://godbolt.org/z/6WbceEqdv) an example for a polymorphic `Model`. In the `main()` you have some usage examples. I implemented a `Point3D` class just to illustrate how it is supposed to be used. _For information, a class becomes polymorphic if and only if it contains at least one virtual member function._

Comment: @Fareanor you misunderstood me : my current model as two parameters of type `T`, but I will have also another model having four parameters of type `T`, or only one parameter of type `std::vector<T>`. Model have parameters of different natures : hence parameter must be polymorphic, an yes it will have a pure virtual function, the `value()` member function.

Comment: @Fareanor I isolated my real problem in minimal example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77600325/modifying-in-class-pointed-objects-through-array-of-base-pointers