# Modifying in-class pointed objects through array of base pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, reference, stdvector

I have a model who has (for now `double`) parameters and produces a `double` output :

```
class Model1
{
    double x_;
    double y_;
    std::array<double*, 2> model_parameters;
    void set_parameters_pointers()
    {
        model_parameters[0] = &x_;
        model_parameters[1] = &y_;
    }
public:
    Model1(const double x, const double y) : x_(x), y_(y)
    {
        set_parameters_pointers();
    }
    const std::array<double*, 2> & parameters() {return model_parameters;}
    double modelOutput()
    {
        return 0.5*(x_*x_+y_*y_);
    }
};
```

I use the pointers array to compute sensitivities of the model to its parameters as follows :

```
int main()
{
    //the model parameters
    double x = 1.0;
    double y = 1.0;
    //the model
    Model1 model1(x,y);
    //the container (array) of model's parameters used to check
    //how model's output varies with parameters
    const std::array<double*, 2> vp = model1.parameters();

    //model's output
    double fxy = model1.modelOutput();
    //bumping model's parameter x up by 1e-8
    *vp[0] += 1e-8;
    //model's post bump new output
    double fpxy = model1.modelOutput();
    //bumping back model's x parameter to it's initial value
    *vp[0] -= 1e-8;
    //model's sensitivity to parameter x
    double fdx = 1e8 * (fpxy - fxy);
    std::cout << fdx << std::endl; //prints 1.0
    return 0;
}
```

In the future `Model1` will be polymorphic and will have parameters of more general natures that only double. For now, let's just wrap up double in a dedicated parameter type as follows :

```
class ConstantNumericalParameter
{
    double &value_;
public:
    ConstantNumericalParameter(double & value) : value_(value) {}
    void tilt_up(const double bumpSize = 1e-8)
    {
        value_ += bumpSize;
    }
    void tilt_down(const double bumpSize = 1e-8)
    {
        value_ -= bumpSize;
    }
};
```

and let's provide a new model based on it :

```
class Model2
{
    double x_;
    double y_;
    std::array<ConstantNumericalParameter*, 2> model_parameters;
    void set_parameters_pointers()
    {
        model_parameters[0] = new ConstantNumericalParameter(x_);
        model_parameters[1] = new ConstantNumericalParameter(y_);
    }
public:
    Model2(const double x, const double y) : x_(x), y_(y)
    {
        set_parameters_pointers();
    }
    const std::array<ConstantNumericalParameter*, 2> & parameters() {return model_parameters;}
    double modelOutput()
    {
        return 0.5*(x_*x_+y_*y_);
    }
};
```

I use this new pointers array to compute model sensitivities to its parameters as follows :

```
int main()
{
    Model2 model2(x,y);
    //the container (array) of typed model's parameters used to check
    //how model's output varies with parameters
    std::array<ConstantNumericalParameter*, 2> vparamp = model2.parameters();
    //model's output
    double fxy = model2.modelOutput();
    //bumping model's parameter x up by 1e-8
    vparamp[0]->tilt_up();
    //model's post bump new output
    double fpxy = model2.modelOutput();
    //bumping back model's x parameter to it's initial value
    vparamp[0]->tilt_down();
    //model's sensitivity to parameter x
    double fdx = 1e8 * (fpxy - fxy);
    std::cout << fdx << std::endl; // still prints 1.0
    return 0;
}
```

So far so good : when I change the `ConstantNumericalParameter` through the array it gets changed inside `Model2` : it is exactly what I want.

Now, I would like my model to have its first parameter `x_` to be an `std::vector<double>` and not "just" a double anymore and I would like to get a new type `VectorNumericalParameter` for wrapping `y_` up, so that both `ConstantNumericalParameter` and `VectorNumericalParameter` would derived from a base class `NumericalParameter`.

I implemented this as follows :

```
class NumericalParameter
{
    public:
    virtual void tilt_up(const double bumpSize = 1e-8) = 0; 
    virtual void tilt_down(const double bumpSize = 1e-8) = 0;
};

class ConstantNumericalParameter : public NumericalParameter
{
    double &value_;
public:
    ConstantNumericalParameter(double & value) : value_(value) {}
    void tilt_up(const double bumpSize = 1e-8) override
    {
        value_ += bumpSize;
    }
    void tilt_down(const double bumpSize = 1e-8) override
    {
        value_ -= bumpSize;
    }
};

class VectorNumericalParameter : public NumericalParameter
{
    std::vector<double> values_;
public:
    VectorNumericalParameter(std::vector<double> & values) : values_(values) {}
    void tilt_up(const double bumpSize = 1e-8) override
    {
        for(auto value : values_)
            value += bumpSize;
    }
    void tilt_down(const double bumpSize = 1e-8) override
    {
        for(auto value : values_)
            value -= bumpSize;
    }
};
```

and a new model class :

```
class Model3
{
    std::vector<double> x_;
    double y_;
    std::array<NumericalParameter*, 2> model_parameters;
    void set_parameters_pointers()
    {
        model_parameters[0] = new VectorNumericalParameter(x_);
        model_parameters[1] = new ConstantNumericalParameter(y_);
    }
public:
    Model3(const std::vector<double> x, const double y) : x_(x), y_(y)
    {
        set_parameters_pointers();
    }
    const std::array<NumericalParameter*, 2> & parameters() {return model_parameters;}
    double modelOutput()
    {
        return 0.5*(x_[0]*x_[0]+y_*y_);
    }
};
```

Using it as follows :

```
int main()
{
    //the model parameters
    double x = 1.0;
    double y = 1.0;

    std::vector<double> vx(1);
    vx[0] = x;
    Model3 model3(vx, y);
    std::array<NumericalParameter*, 2> vparamp2 = model3.parameters();
    //model's output
    double fxy = model3.modelOutput();
    //bumping model's parameter x up by 1e-8
    vparamp2[0]->tilt_up();
    //model's post bump new output
    double fpxy = model3.modelOutput();
    //bumping back model's x parameter to it's initial value
    vparamp2[0]->tilt_down();
    //model's sensitivity to parameter x
    double fdx = 1e8 * (fpxy - fxy);
    std::cout << fdx << std::endl; // prints 0.0 instead of 1.0 :(
    return 0;
}
```

but it doesn't work as the index 0 first coefficient of `y_` is not changed when it gets tilted from the parameters array. How could I fix this ?

(The complete code is [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QAJgAMfAQQCqAZ0wAFAB6cpvAFYgupWkwahkAUgkAhcxdLL6yAngGVG6AMKpaAVxYNJ%2B1wAZPAZMADkfACNMYj0AFhkAB1RFQicGD29ff1Jk1McBYNCIlmjYrgTbTHsChiECJmICTJ8/CX07TAd0%2BsaCIvComPiZRQamluz223H%2BkMHS4YqpAEpbVC9iZHYOcwBmEORvLABqUz23JzHiTFZz7FMpAEF9w%2BPMM4vG4iYAT3vHi8JAcGEcvKdzm4AG5dIjEAHPQFHJiKRQnACyGGqXEBpgA7FZnidiSd0BtIvQTmoAPrnQlPEmk8mU360vb0xljdAgEDfP6QsleCmYABUpBOEnuJxYWNo1MSjVYmAIMUUdMBjKhqDw6BOygI8sVbBVxEU8u1glVEBWGpJ%2BI5jJJMqwcoVP2NqtMAFYLFJvQART6B8wANhp6qJjuJzuqhvdys9PpxXuDe2DEhDrIjDLteP9gMSQtoeGQIFtxMxLq4EDQDDGTKLHzU4tr9cFwpOvxWJxAVOpEDUa07/a75bOBLHnOVcaVJrNyRCc%2Bt2cZ%2BPzkeJrYIeoI3N5xB%2B/wu7foYolUtDJzds6t3ftNwImwY0tlM49pvVebHJ4%2BMdoAHkvAIQsCGXDdxwdKMHyfE4pAAOi9EUB2pEVw0sVkRVZG12THNdcS/HDESIl5nmRVEThKGISzEFQjQTeFEQncDCwpEsy3AqE8CaLwxBOLUdRORxaANLxEhrAQ22ZD5Ih8RIhDwAAvD5zkDLhMAAWgADjvNNYLpM4OK4x9eP43UhINMkAHcGHEuttx/E4ZJYOTFOU3S1K0nTAz9QiXgI%2BkkUMciPDsowCEo4hqNoWj4xNHsryLEsKJ8KjRGiuiTXwyCGw7UMoTELxMDZekWOLUsxxCsYwoiqKYpvYgIAcy98u8TBu17FrCv7Tq2ogvCOO1My6BEsStxyyknJcpSgxODztJOVAYQPHVMFwpicyjHrqTOSwVMc2T5KUldc3XDa%2BMGwThupKybLGhzJsOtzVI0%2BbFpiSKsDW7LNQKoqTnUvaHtc47iX6vz818wKUTRStqklRjsoc8NfMZBysxRkkuR5PkjzcSqGkEGq0rq98z0lPZsBfF033otUMeJUy9Wna933nC0lxtcD7UnJ1XxZ2nvV9AMZtCSyTnx6qUsi4mMpiZDsO%2B3nqf5udBeTVNA1F8WJIJ8Kpdq2WGqwkHx1O0q2LHWHaAkWzJMbKkWx18aPi7eKaQHIdWQgUcufWqNiX1Gm53NRdbxNsHGTGrH90PSEJcJ/WZdimIyYvDMr0NxRrQg6DiGfP8g89HCv3Ahy/0A4CgLAs7ufAxlc%2BfeDEOQ1DaXQlDjfp038IhgLSKCtEADVYRIImaMN%2BLzeQZK2Gl8fk4YvzsujmEHBIAUpKlHqzWzKf2LO4e1%2BIMf0oXiAV5H%2BFj03imdpDPjfsUdqH9as0IG3u8JxLs7GfM6lRNtvZKS%2B1nKPRmnNbsb1lqfV9orYk/AGpMCAqgF%2BhV4rb2pJzM6/tUHKV2rpIGR0u4RxJL/K6N1AHOxAVNJ6s0XqQKWh9VasCebwJIBAJBRBcHoMfpg1hjoer/UBgdYGxDv54Uhv3aGGJZR7CymOC%2BR8N6NilMjRGwD0bL13NjA8/ILgnxJvRVOt8C4qyLtlRmgczGmhDpaU01dVx%2B39qYzOgs/QphFpgMWh84QGMNvLE2jIXELzVEmYWe0tbxz1rPA2Z9O7ZTBnvS2sjKGKLhMo4UqjHZ2Soa7Xs7tBzii9j7GuTioxWMzrYjm4dv6RydtHHGkI/EL2MZTS81is6fwsA3KmsYOmflOqjYB5cgIgQcbmOBJwelNyQuGH07j/StzcQGawGF4lrVOhIvuTxFzSiYCEautczoAHpjkEAQL%2BWUGcQnfmAWocBcEfLqPtr8B5TyxynPOZcl0ySqy9NoNWZso4u6fIuScWsDR5jEBOBw3RrtUBUH%2BWADgaIOknC8MoMyKDkAXOQAAaw%2BcchAqAxZ/mRWiDYldtz5UipgNEllCAIGufVNU4Eo7aJjnotwP5Wl8USDNP8XA4IdOXJIk5xyyUooWqMoCtz7ZUDUK8vagq4IjKpaK7KpzJohGAEiqV1iqTov5ZEV5c0xwiihIkZZHjrB7TNSCiVspyVXhSNuSaJwtaUpAnKjsVBEiKoFbKIVaqxkK0Jdq4wjkmD4r1Wie5BquGEGdSENIJlfrmstdawMAN3IvRNqcyVaJlB1jSJxAgryuEGrUD6ykVB0D3LtZgTSJwRQwr9QG9SJwFXAq0XuNAQFPhuEhF2%2Btg7h3R1cLQbMhKqBGGQL8HVgkEA6rREwRyhBflw3%2BTbIFYbwKgo%2BBC/ZoRoWwsPJAxF5bEiYF1IW5lrN0WYsEti3FBL91EpJbG6VVKH60vpYy%2B9AtwINLhXHHWksYlJ3qryy1Rp%2BXKtlBIYVmcNWErvV62V4Fu2BpdEhkNVc93iojbqu9VajWOVNXmjiLMrXzIDDm7Af8AGEcZAWp1%2BrXXUI9V4793qsP%2BqVbpP8eHZQV1Dfm45xGo0xrvfGieiaCDJoYKm2guCxywfdLRoWKYGN/woSxkkbGXTOuLfkPAZaK0oKrWOOtDbc3NtbdQAT/0u2KoMwHDl/btyQmHbZsdFwdx7kndO99s7QQLsjecldJxMAwnziQZhZ00nr2vio2%2BUI1AQC4O5vi1a6M2t0tWruVs9j/L2O/ZsnYcsgdjvoxO89oPinJpTDTrBEgSBw9UPYyGQmoffehmVBAbMBoQy6br%2BHQI5a1bJRdpGJ73NEhRuhWl1M0clPl/0umrrMYk6Rzj7rPWDZs850bXXVWicG31ojM3I2RGjXir9cmF7PpOEmqVKbHBptaqtuD63tObfuHpklNkpuOuM1K0zpbCCWcA3FatWHR2Noc225znbu3Vc85S/zbgR12aHQFidDB0BTrFbicC0zp15g4GsWgnAvS8D8BwLQpBUCcCHbtSweoNhbDwXsHgpACCaGp2sPFIAvQyFpxwOIDOhcs84LwRQIAZCC6Z9T0gcBYAwEQCgVAzk6AxHIJQNAev6CxGAFwPYEg%2BDDVVJQSIsvIghEaL8Tg/PHfMGIL8f8kRtCwld7wY3bBBD/gYLQF3qvSBYBksANwYhaCK%2B4LwLALAjDAHEBH/ANxugwgT8zzAaguhAR2Pz0OkvmfFkiD8T3HgsCy4IJFFg/u1hUEMMARQg88BeP/Nexn/P%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%2BGK7K4vGkCi6KGS57B0EqF%2BHiHC4bESBQkAkcDPGq6SGkBLSpDOBxBAA).)

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: why do you not use a reference here `std::vector<double> values_;` for the member of `VectorNumericalParameter` like you did here `double &value_;` for the `ConstantNumericalParameter` ? Thats the reason why it doesnt work as you expect. You are looking at two different vectors, one is getting modified, the other is a copy of the unmodified

Comment: If I put `std::vector<double> & values_;` it doesn,'t change the behaviour.

Comment: yes, I was a bit too fast when I wrote "Thats the reason". Its one reason it cannot work as expected, seems like there is more