# vector Initialize reference from return value

Tags: c++, reference, stdvector

I have a model class :

```
template <class T>
class Model
{
    T x_; //model parameter 1
    T y_; //model parameter 2
    std::vector<T*> parameters_; // vector of pointers to model parameters
    void set_param_pointers() // setting the parameters pointers vector
    {
        parameters_[0] = &x_;
        parameters_[1] = &y_;
    }
public:
    template <class U>
    Model(const U x, const U y) : x_(x), y_(y), parameters_(2)
    {
        set_param_pointers();
    }
    T expensive_method() const // an method numerically (CPU + RAM) expensive
    {
        return 0.5 * (x_ * x_ + y_ * y_);
    }
    const std::vector<T*>& params() { return parameters_; }
};
```

Let's say I instantiate a `Model<double>` with two parameters in client code, code in which I get my instance's `parameters_` by ref with `params()`, whose coeffs I then use to change the `x_` and `y_` of my instance, to see how the expensive method behave regarding to those changes. For instance :

```
Model<double> model(1.0, 1.0);
const auto baseRes = model.expensive_method();
const auto params = model.params();
for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); ++i)
{
    *params[i] += 1e-8; // changing the parameter by bumping it up by 1e-8
    auto bumpRes = model.expensive_method();
    *params[i] -= 1e-8; // switching the param back to its initial value
    std::cout << 1e8 * (bumpRes - baseRes) << std::endl; // I print out the sensitivity of my `expensive_method` to the i-th param
}
```

(In this point of view the `std::vector<T*>` is just a container for `T*`'s, I could have used an array for instance, and I use this container to modify my `Model` instance's params etc.)

I am happy with this set-up, yet it is very poor regarding to the nature of `x_` and `y_` : they can only be of type `T`. I would indeed like to allow more generality in the nature of my model parameters. The first step is to factor out my parameter (and its change) in a class :

```
template <class T>
class X
{
    T & value_;
public:
    template <class U>
    X(U & value) : value_(value) {}
    void tilt_up()
    {
        value_ += T(1.0);
    }
    void tilt_down()
    {
        value_ -= T(1.0);
    }
};
```

`Model` changes as follows :

```
template <class T>
class Model
{
    T x_; //model parameter 1
    T y_; //model parameter 2
    std::vector<X<T>*> parameters_; // vector of pointers to model parameters
    void set_param_pointers() // setting the parameters pointers vector
    {
        parameters_[0] = new X<T>(x_);
        parameters_[1] = new X<T>(y_);
    }
public:
    template <class U>
    Model(const U x, const U y) : x_(x), y_(y), parameters_(2)
    {
        set_param_pointers();
    }
    T expensive_method() const // an method numerically (CPU + RAM) expensive
    {
        return 0.5 * (x_ * x_ + y_ * y_);
    }
    const std::vector<T*>& params() { return parameters_; }
};
```

and client code as follows :

```
Model<double> model(1.0, 1.0);
const auto baseRes = model.expensive_method();
const auto params = model.params();
for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); ++i)
{
    params[i]->tilt_up() ; // changing the parameter by bumping it up by 1e-8
    auto bumpRes = model.expensive_method();
    params[i]->tilt_down(); // switching the param back to its initial value
    std::cout << 1e8 * (bumpRes - baseRes) << std::endl; // I print out the sensitivity of my `expensive_method` to the i-th param
}
```

Now, I would `X` to derive from `XB` defined as :

```
template <class T>
class XB
{
public:
    virtual void tilt_up() = 0;
    virtual void tilt_down() = 0;
};
```

and my `Model`'s `params_` to be a `std::vector<XB<T>*> parameters_` with the obvious changes.

Now my "design" problem really begins : imagine I am not satified with `y_` being a `T` (I call this case "simple case") and that I want it to be now an `std::vector<T>` for instance - I call this case "second case". (I could also want it to be a `matrix<T>` where `matrix` is a custom matrix type, or other things.) The new `X` class should have a `std::vector<T> &` data member, and the tilting method should tilt all the vector coefficients, but I don't see at all how to design such a new version of `X`.

My first issue is with the templated constructor

```
template <class U>
X(std::vector<U> & values) : value_(/* have to put something here */) {}
```

In the simple case `value_(value)`, as far as I figure, is understood as : in my use case I have an explicit ctor `T(U)` (in my case `U` is `double` and `T` is a custom and quite intricate type, for instance [this one](https://github.com/asavine/CompFinance/blob/master/AADExpr.h))) so that I really need my `template <class U> Model` ctor. In the second case, an `std::vector<U>` will never be castable into an `std::vector<U>`, so in place of `/* have to put something here */` I though putting return value of :

```
template <class T, class U>
std::vector<T> & CastTo(std::vector<U> &input)
{
    std::vector<T> output;
    for (auto obj : input)
        output.push_back(T(obj));
    return output;
}
```

but it didn't work because of some problem of returning local variable. How could I achieved the behaviour I want in the second case ?

Comment: Are you really sure you want a reference member in your X class? In the `CastTo` function it is totally fine to return output. In old versions of C++ that would result in an unecessary copy, in current C++ it will not even really be a local variable (lookup RVO, return value optimization)

Comment: @PepijnKramer Initially I had a class with `T` data members (that I called parameters) and an array of `T*` data member whose coefficients point to the `T` data members of the class (I call array of params this array). I had a ref getter to this vector, so that I could change the `T` data members etc. I wanted to "generalize" that behaviour in case I wanted other parameters than `T`, for instance `std::vector<T>`. So I wrapped up the `T`'s first the X class, and asked myself how to treat the `std::vector<T>` case, hence my question. (Tell me if it is clear.)

Comment: @PepijnKramer My real target is having a base class `B` of params, derived classes of concrete params that can represent either `T`'s, or `std::vector<T>`'s, or matrices of `T`'s, that I store in an array of `B*` and that I can modify by referring to coeffficients of that array an using `tilt_up` which would be a pure virtual function in `B`.

Comment: Maybe you mean something like a view on data inside the matrix? Something like [mdspan](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/mdspan) perhaps? Better explained here : [Multidimensional C++ - Bryce Adelstein Lelbach - CppNorth 2022](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=aFCLmQEkPUw)

Comment: @PepijnKramer No. I will detail even more the in the "context" part of my question I already added.

Comment: Could we have a [mre] please?  As currently formulated, I find the question hard to follow.

Comment: @PaulSanders I already provided a minimal reproducible example here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77600325/modifying-in-class-pointed-objects-through-array-of-base-pointers and you couldn't honestrly say it revealed itself to be succesful for me ... ;)

Comment: Can't say I agree.  Anyway, this is this question, not that question.

Comment: @PaulSanders what are you disagreeing with ? WIth the minimality of the other question ? (It's an honest question, cause would I clarify this one so that you could follow, I would naturally tend to ask something very close to the other question - which hasn't collected success, except an irrelevant comment, hence my doubts.) I'll still try, you'll tell me.

Comment: @PaulSanders I detailed with a minimal example.

Comment: `template <class U> X(U & value) : value_(value) {}` doesn't really make sense. It would only compile if `T == U`, or if `T` is a class and `U` is a class derived from it (but in your example, `T` and `U` are apparently meant to be scalars). In other cases it'd fail because it tries to bind a non-const reference to a temporary (the result of converting `U` to `T`).

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I use it only with a `T` equal to a custom type into which `double` can be casted and with `value` a `double`, and it works. I provided a templated example because I don't quite really grasp all of what what can be done in untemplated that cannot in templated code and I didn't want to risk an answer to an untemplateed example that wouldn't have worked in my templated setup.

Comment: Can you show what this "custom type into which `double` can be casted"? I don't quite understand how this part could work.

Comment: ... And this is why a [mre] is so important.  Without one, people flail around in the dark.  So please read up on what it actually is, and then post a *single* code snippet which we can simply copy and paste into our favourite compiler and then play around with it.  (You still haven't done that.)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the custom type in question could someting like `Number` from here : https://github.com/asavine/CompFinance/blob/master/AADExpr.h

Comment: @PaulSanders do you realize that what you ask isn't always possible ? (I mean, in my case, it is really hard to do it. Plus if you post mainly (too much) code you have warning before posting etc.) I really tried my best here, without posting a ton of code only.

Comment: So, do you have `X<Number>` that stores a reference to `Number`, but whose constructor takes a `double&`? Where is the instance of `Number` stored that the reference ends up referring to? I suspect that, if you somehow got it to compile, you end up storing a dangling reference.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I got it to compile (last visual c++ compiler, c++-20 option), and it does the correct job when executed. `Model<Number>` has a `Number` data member wihch can be `double` thanks to `U` and the stored reference you mention will point to that data member.

Comment: So you have `Model` that stores members of type `Number`, and constructs `X<Number>` instances referring to those members. Then you don't need a templated constructor: `X<Number>`'s constructor only needs to take `Number&` as a parameter. By the same token, if `Model` stores say `vector<double>`, it would wrap a reference to it into `X<vector<double>>`; or if it stores `vector<Number>` it would create a corresponding `X<vector<Number>>`. So you don't need a templated constructor with mismatched types, and the issue becomes moot, does it not?

Comment: @11house Did you read what's behind the link?  It asks you to boil your problem down to the essentials, not post your entire codebase.  If that takes a bit of work, so beit.  But it's the way things work around here, it's the best way to get help.  As it is, Igor is doing his best, but you're tying him in knots.

Comment: Or else, can you show a situation where you would actually need to call `X<T>::X(U&)` constructor with `U` different from `T`?

Comment: @PaulSanders I did read it, yes, I really think I boiled it down to the bare minimum. I just think it's not always possible. I am sorry.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The client code with `Model<Number>` instead of `Model<double>` and all other things remaning unchanged works, for instance.

Comment: Yes it works, because `Model<Number>` creates instances of `X<Number>` and passes `Number&` references to those instances. It would work just as well with `X`'s constructor not being a template. What **doesn't** work if you make `X`'s constructor not a template? Why do you insist on making it a template?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Ok, I think I see what you mean. In my code I removed the `U`-templatization from the constructor and got this error : "cannot convert lvalue of type double to parameter type 'Number' because ctor Number(const double val) is explicit". (It is indeed explicit.) So I was completely wrong saying that `double is castable` to my custom type. (For instance `operator+=` is overloaded to accept also incrementing a custom type by a double.) So I indeed need the `U`-templatization for my ctor. (And sorry for being a noob.)

Comment: But where do you pass a `double` and try to assign or cast it to a `Number`? `Model<T>` only ever passes a `T` to `X<T>`, never a type different from `T`. Exactly which line of code produces the error you cite?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik For instance in the same client code as the one I provided but in which you would use `Model<Number>` (instantiated with `double`s `1.0` and `1.0`) instead of `Model<double>`. (The `Number` type is a case of the so called automatic differentation where you augment `double`, leading to new, for which when you do all double operations and functions, you do at the same time the derivatives of these operations.)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik (For instance if `f` is a templated function whose definition involves operations/functions defined for `double` and `Number`, then, if `x` is a double, computing `f(x)` will give you what you expected, but computing `f(Number(x))` will give the value of f on x but also; at the same time, the value of the derivative of f at x.)

Comment: I understand where `Model` might need a templated constructor. I don't understand where `X` would need one. For `Model`, it's OK - it doesn't attempt to store references to the constructor's arguments. For `X`, it's not OK because it in fact does.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik the `new`s from `set_param_pointers` would not work in the `Model<Number>` case would the ctor from `X` not be `U`-templated.

Comment: Why not? Your code shows `new X<T>(x_)` where `x_` is of type `T`. So for `Model<Number>`, that would call `X<Number>(Number&)` constructor, would it not? What type `U` different from `T` do you believe the constructor would need to accept in this case?